# Yum: No package mysql-server available in Cent OS 7

Tags: centos, mysql, yum, centos7

I just installed Apache on my new Digital Ocean Cent OS 7 x64 server. When following Digital Ocean's tutorial, yum cannot install mysql-server.

```
# yum install mysql mysql-server mysql-libs mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.usinternet.com
 * extras: mirror.cogentco.com
 * updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
Package 1:mariadb-5.5.40-2.el7_0.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package mysql-server available.
Package 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-2.el7_0.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package mysql-server available.
Nothing to do

# service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

This is my 3rd server setting up mysql, but this one has stumped me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In RHEL 7, and consequently in CentOS7, the `mysql-` packages (or most of them, anyway) have been replaced with `mariadb-` packages due to an upstream rename/fork. Simply `yum install mariadb-server mariadb-libs mariadb` and you should be okay - the command names themselves are still mostly `mysql` related.

Comment: So to manage the mysql-server, I should use `service mariadb [command]`?

Comment: `service mysql start ...
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysql.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysql.service failed to load: No such file or directory.` and `service mysqld start ...
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

Comment: Not quite - RHEL/CentOS 7 use the `systemctl` suite, not the `service` suite. So yes, you'll be using `mariadb` as the name, but the command will be `systemctl start mariadb.service`

Answer (score 5):

As answered by John mysql is replaced with mariadb in RHEL 7 and later, but you can still install mysql. Follow the following steps:

1. Download and add the repository, then update.

   > wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
   >   sudo rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
   >   yum update
2. Install MySQL as usual and start the service. During installation, you will be asked if you want to accept the results from the .rpm file’s GPG verification. If no error or mismatch occurs, enter `y`.

   > sudo yum install mysql-server
   >   sudo systemctl start mysqld

Ref: [linode](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7)

Answer (score 1):

On any RPM based OS you can find which package provides MySQL server:

```
yum provides "*bin/mysqld"
```